# SSRS and Visual Studio new version

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, upgrade

I have recently upgraded my Visual Studio from version 2015 to version 2017.  The solution I have was a version 2015 report but was upgraded to version 2017 using the internal upgrade question.  Now when I run the report I get a non explicit error

An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.

Comment: start by testing datasources, then datasets. It could be credentials have been lost during the conversion.

Comment: The datasources are correct and the credentials are also correct.

Comment: Are there any errors listed in the error window?

Comment: Nope ... I wish I had more to go on.  Is there an issue with upgrading or something?  How about another log somewhere?